# Django 1.9 sqlflush ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to erase my SQL database with

```
django-admin sqlflush
```

but getting the following error message. I can't understand what it is reacting on.

```
C:\Dropbox\django\group_project>django-admin sqlflush
Traceback (most recent call last):
es\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "c:\users\filip\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\db\utils.py", line 157, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "c:\users\filip\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\filip\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but se
ttings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANG
O_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: is you DATABASES settings correct?

Comment: @Zgr3doo do you mean the modelling?

Comment: In `settings.py`, did you provide your database settings?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro just having default DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell `django-admin` what project's DB you want to flush. There are a few options:

- Use `python manage.py sqlflush` instead.
- Use `django-admin sqlflush --settings=mysite.settings` where `mysite.settings` is your settings module.
- Set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in your operating system to `mysite.settings` where `mysite.settings` is your settings module. Then you can use `django-admin sqlflush`.